# Stuck on Building wheel for opencv-contrib-python (pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to install opencv-python but it is always stuck at: `Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml)`. I tried installing the older versions but it happens with all of them, just stays at building wheel for an hour and nothing happens. I have done `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` as well but no success yet.

OS: MacOS Mojave // Command: pip3 install opencv-python

[image]

Someone help, I cant find a fix anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this command?

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66 --verbose
```